# Bound for a sequence of indicator functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\{x_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, such that: $x_k\to x$. Let $R>0$. Is true that: $\chi_{B_R(x_k)}\leq\chi_{B_{2R}(x)}$ a.e. on $\mathbb{R}^n$, for $k$ large? In this case can you give me a rigorous proof please?

Comment: Notice that $\chi_{B_R(x_k)} \leqslant \chi_{B_{2R}(x)}$ if and only if $B_R(x_k) \subset B_{2R}(x)$

Comment: Just use $\|y-x\|\leq \|y-x_k\|+\|x_k-x\|<\|x_k-y\|+R$ if $k$ is large enough.